# npm installaton stops at "Starting 'create theme.config'..."

Tags: npm, npm-install

Help!?

When installing the latest version of semantic-ui on Windows 10 x64, after downloading and installing the pkg through npm, setup (not build) launches automatically (looks to be running in gulp)

[screenshot of install messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYCF4.png)

Several install messages show:

1. "Installing to semantic/"
2. a few copying/adding messsages
3. **"Starting 'create theme.config'..."**
4. **"adjusting @sitefolder"**
5. then finally **"creating src/theme.config (LESS config) c:\users\xxxxx ..."**

And that is where it stops. No CPU or disk activity shows in process monitor, nothing, nada, zip.

If I cancel this process semantic-ui doesn't seem to get installed.

MORE INFO - npm-cache log file shows:

116 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open xxx...\package.json'
117 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

yup, no PACKAGE.JSON file there, but there is a PACKAGE-LOCK.JSON file, so I created a new PACKAGE.JSON file via "NPM INIT" but still same problem.

ANY IDEAS HERE?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: This issue is still open on semantic-ui github: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6641